# How to set a timer in wp7 applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7, timer

How can I set a timer to run from code?  I can't find any control named `timer`.

What are the steps needed to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DispatcherTimer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
dt.Tick += delegate { ... };
dt.Start();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.interval%28v=vs.95%29.aspx  You can create a `TimeSpan` using its constructor or by writing `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't seen the hyper-link in your answer.